# Keeping state between debug runs of a Python function in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a Python function that I need to debug, and I am primarily developing in Visual Studio Code. The inputs to the function include two data frames, one of which takes over six minutes to load.

Is there a way in the Visual Studio Code debugger to hold on to state between debug sessions so that each debug run does not start with the same six minutes loading data?

Instead I can do my debugging via a Jupyter Notebook, and hold on to the state that way, but then I lose all the IDE debugging support like breakpoints.

Comment: You should investigate *why* it takes 6 minutes and try to improve that. You could also try to use pickle. Loading a pickle file might be faster than reading and converting a large csv/excel file to a dataframe. pandas has its own `read_pickle` and `to_pickle` methods

Comment: Yep, there's a lot of data. I tried pickle and it was slower than CSV. But that's not what I am asking about.

Comment: The answer to the actual question is "no", once you restart the interpreter you lose all the data that was in memory. That is why I suggested pickling